# How to control the sampling rate on the App from the smart-insole android studio?

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

in my case, I got the data from the insole by Bluetooth and the data will be transmitted to App, then the App will store the data to firebase. the problem is now the insole use 1Hz frequency and I want to change the frequency to 55Hz. it is possible or not if I want change the sampling rate of the insole? Because I was read lots of references and for changing the sampling rate it only works for Audio format.

Comment: Hi @Jakaria, Bluetooth is not running for 55Hz or 1Hz. What do you mean 55Hz and 1Hz here ?

Comment: Hi @MiloChen, the frequency as I mention above, is for sampling rate data. the problem is I was received data from the insole and transmitted it to App. but it's too slow, so I need to increase the speed. then my professor told me to change the sampling rate of the insole from 1Hz to 55Hz. so I ask here is it possible if I want to change the frequency of sampling rate? because I can't find any reference for changing the BLE frequency.

Comment: The standard BLE frequency is not so low like you said. 
You can check ble core specification.  
iOS follow the standard BLE frequency to implement BLE  API. In the application layer, you cannot change the frequency.